# make tree structure from flatten array based on leftIndent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, data-structures

[tree-view-example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMhx8.png)

Need to make tree structure from flattening array based on `leftIndent` to the tree.
It needs to make tree folders view like in the library [react-vtree](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-vtree).
Added screenshot for understanding task.

```
const from = [
  {
    id: 1,
    data: {
      leftIndent: 0,
      text: 'L',
    },
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    data: {
      leftIndent: 18,
      text: 'M',
    },
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    data: {
      leftIndent: 0,
      text: 'X',
    },
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    data: {
      leftIndent: 18,
      text: 'Y',
    },
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    data: {
      leftIndent: 36,
      text: 'Z',
    },
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    data: {
      leftIndent: 36,
      text: 'S',
    },
  },
];

const to = [
  {
    id: 0,
    data: {
      leftIndent: 0,
      text: 'L',
    },
    children: [
      {
        id: 2,
        data: {
          leftIndent: 18,
          text: 'M',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    data: {
      leftIndent: 0,
      text: 'X',
    },
    children: [
      {
        id: 4,
        data: {
          leftIndent: 18,
          text: 'Y',
        },
        children: [
          {
            id: 5,
            data: {
              leftIndent: 36,
              text: 'Z',
            },
          },
          {
            id: 6,
            data: {
              leftIndent: 36,
              text: 'S',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      const makeTree = (branches) => {
    function topLevel(data) {
      return data.filter((node) => !node.parentId);
    }

    function traverse(data, parentId) {
      const children = data.filter((branch) => branch.parentId === parentId);
      children.forEach((child) => {
        child.children = traverse(data, child.id);
      });
      return children;
    }

    return topLevel(branches).map((branch) => {
      branch.children = traverse(branches, branch.id);
      return branch;
    });
  };

  const makeFlattenNumberingArray = (paragraphs) => {
    const resultArr = [];
    let levelData = null;
    let route = '';

    // iterate over all array
    for (let i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {
      const curr = paragraphs[i];
      let level = 0; // reset level to `0`. Top level.
      let parentId = null;
      // this loop need only for finding deep level
      for (let j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        const prev = resultArr[j];
        // we need check current paragraph with previous, if current !== previous paragraph need to look higher(backward loop)
        if (curr.data.leftIndent > prev.data.leftIndent) {
          level = prev.level + 1;
          parentId = prev.id;
          break;
        }
      }

      levelData = {
        id: curr.id,
        data: curr.data,
        children: [],
        parentId,
        level
      };

      resultArr.push(levelData);
    }
    return resultArr;
  };

const paragraphs = makeFlattenNumberingArray(data);

const tree = makeTree(paragraphs);
```